# Application of derivative - Want to know the relation of graph with this problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem :

For the curve $y = 3 \sin \theta \cos \theta, x = e^\theta \sin \theta, 0 \leq  \theta \leq \pi $ ; the tangent is parallel to x-axis when $\theta$  is

a) $0$

b) $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

c)  $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

d) $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$

Solution : We will find $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$ with the help of this we will find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ which should be equal to 0 so that slope will be parallel to x axis.

$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} = -3(\cos^2\theta -\sin^2 \theta)$ ;

$\dfrac{dx}{d\theta} = e^{\theta} \cos\theta +\sin\theta e^{\theta}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-3(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{e^{\theta} \cos\theta +\sin\theta e^{\theta}}$

If we put $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -3(\cos\theta-\sin\theta) = 0  \Rightarrow \cos\theta = \sin\theta $

$\therefore \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Now my question is how can we show $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} $ and $ \dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$ graphically.   Thanks...

Comment: **Hint:** Choose $\theta$ to be one of the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the parameter $\theta$ of the curve as *time*, and the curve itself at a given moment $\theta$ as the location of an ant, say. Then the vector $(\frac{dx}{d\theta},\,\frac{dy}{d\theta})$ is just the *velocity* vector of the moving of the ant.

A path can be walked through in many-many ways, choosing other magnitudes for velocities, however, it is always true that at the point $(x(\theta),\,y(\theta))$, the velocity vector is *tangent* to the path.